# Sumif function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, sum

I'm having issues in doing Excel's SUMIF function in R. There are 2 matrices, m and n. I want matrix n to take the sum of each column j of matrix m limited until the i-th row if the row i+1 in column j+1 is not empty (not sure if I made this clear, below are my explanation for a clearer view of what I want to do).

Below are my codes:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,'',7,'',''), nrow = 3)

n <- matrix('', nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

for (j in 1:2) {
  n[2,j] <- sum(as.numeric(m[,j])[!is.na(m[,j+1])]
}

n[2,3] <- ''
```

Below is matrix m:

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,'',7,'',''), nrow = 3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "1"  "4"  "7" 
[2,] "2"  "5"  ""  
[3,] "3"  ""   ""
```

The above codes yield the results for matrix n:

```
> n <- matrix('', nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
> n
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] ""   ""   ""  
[2,] ""   ""   ""
```

But I want the codes to yield this results:

```
> n <- matrix('', nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
> n
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] ""   ""   ""  
[2,] "3"  "4"  ""
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you forcing `character` and then `sum(as.numeric(.))`? It'd be far better to use `NA` for empty values in your matrix.

Comment: Also why do you need first row as empty ("") in `n` when you have value only in second row?

Comment: Thanks for your response @r2evans! But changing the '' into NA doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: @RonakShah this is a simple and short extraction from my R shiny app which is more complex than this. I want to put the sumif values into the 2nd row of the second matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numeric data:

```r
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,NA,NA), nrow = 3)
n <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
```

Bottom line up-front:

```r
n[2,] <- colSums(m * cbind(!is.na(m)[,-1], FALSE), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Stepping through the logic:

1. Find `NA`s and shift one column to the left:

   ```r
   cbind(!is.na(m)[,-1], FALSE)
   #       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
   # [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
   # [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
   # [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```
2. We can multiply that by the original `m`, where `FALSE` is effectively `0`.

   ```r
   m * cbind(!is.na(m)[,-1], FALSE)
   #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
   # [1,]    1    4    0
   # [2,]    2    0   NA
   # [3,]    0   NA   NA
   ```
3. Column sums, using `colSums(..., na.rm = TRUE)`

   ```r
   colSums(m * cbind(!is.na(m)[,-1], FALSE), na.rm = TRUE)
   # [1] 3 4 0
   ```
4. Assign that value to the second row of `n`:

   ```r
   n[2,] <- colSums(m * cbind(!is.na(m)[,-1], FALSE), na.rm = TRUE)
   n
   #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
   # [1,]   NA   NA   NA
   # [2,]    3    4    0
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @r2evans, this works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

A matrix can hold only one class so having empty character values (`""`) changes all the numeric variables to character. You can use `NA` instead which will keep the class intact and you can `sum` it. Also, I don't really understand why you need additional empty (or NA) rows when your actual data is present only in the last row.

Having said that, you can use `apply` column-wise to `sum` the values till the last non-NA value is found in that column - 1.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,NA,NA), nrow = 3)
n <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
n[2, ] <- apply(m, 2, function(x) sum(x[seq_len(max(which(!is.na(x))) - 1)]))
n

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    3    4    0
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, but how do I convert this vector back to matrix with 2 rows like the matrix n above?